# .Update() returns "Cannot update identity column"

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

There is a link on an Index-type display that directs control to the method below. The Voucher Status is updated to "Reconciled" then a save is attempted.

Everything appears to execute as it should until the Update/Save when I get the exception, "Cannot update identity column."

There are no navigation properties in the Voucher model. Both Identity columns are populated nicely on insert.

The model is here:

```
public class Voucher
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string VoucherId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int64 VoucherNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string VoucherType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime VoucherCreateDate { get; set; }

        [Required]

        public string VoucherStatus { get; set; }
}

public ViewResult ReconcileVoucher(string id) //, Voucher voucher)
        {
            Voucher voucher = _context.Vouchers
                .Single(m => m.VoucherId == id);

            if (id != voucher.VoucherId)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("InputStatus", "Indicated Voucher is not present " + voucher.FullName);
                return View();
            }

            voucher.VoucherStatus = "Reconciled";

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(voucher);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    ModelState.AddModelError("InputStatus", "Voucher was Reconciled for " + voucher.FullName);
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
                {
                    CreateLogRow("Reconcile Voucher", "testUser", "Concurrency exception for " + voucher.StudentId, ex.Message);
                    if (!VoucherExists(voucher.VoucherId))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("InputStatus", "The Voucher for " + voucher.FullName + " cannot be found");
                        return View();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                CreateLogRow("Reconcile Voucher", "testUser", "Voucher was edited for " + voucher.StudentId + " -  " + voucher.FullName, null);
                return View();
            }
            return View(voucher);
        }
```

Comment: Why are `VoucherId` and `StudentId` strings?

Comment: VoucherID is a GUID. Student ID is handled as a string.

Comment: While David Browne's answer undoubtedly is correct (and an answer on this question), in my specific case with UnitOfWork and repositories (very much not like this question), I was only able to make the proposed solution below, by StevePy, to work.  So if your dealing with a similar problem, check out his proposal below too. (below the accepted answer) Thx @ michaelcoder for his kind understanding of this comment spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're marking all the properties as modified by calling

```
 _context.Update(voucher);
```

Either omit this call and let the change tracker determine the updated columns, or explicitly mark the VoucherNumber property as unmodified.

```
db.Update(voucher);
db.Entry(voucher).Property(nameof(Voucher.VoucherNumber)).IsModified = false;
```

Comment: While this worked on this model, I do have a related model, with a concurrency check enabled, that does not save the changes properly without the Update() call. 
It executes the .Save() method, the changes are in the model, no exceptions are thrown but no changes are made to the table.
This type of behavior makes it very difficult to estimate effort required.

Comment: Well you need the current value of any properties configured as Concurrency Tokens to update in that case.  If you're client doesn't pass them up, you may have to fetch the Entity by ID before applying the change.

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch an entity from the DbContext within the call and update property, you should not call `Update`, but rather just call `SaveChanges`.

I.e.

```
Voucher voucher = _context.Vouchers
    .Single(m => m.VoucherId == id);

// ...
voucher.VoucherStatus = "Reconciled";
// ...
_context.SaveChanges();
```

`Update` will generate a statement that will update *all* columns on an entity, and while that should exclude columns that are marked as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` this may not be the case here. By letting the change tracking do its thing without the Update call, EF will generate an UPDATE statement for just the column(s) that changed.

`Update` would be more applicable when accepting an entity (as you had commented out) and attaching/updating its state as a whole. I don't recommend this approach as it overwrites all values and is vulnerable to a number of issues including stale data updates plus unexpected tampering from the client. (Modifying columns your UI does not allow by man-in-the-browser/middle attacks)  It is better to load the entity fresh, validate incoming data, check row versions/modified timestamps for stale updates, etc. rather than accepting an entity at face value and pushing it onto the DB.

Edit: If these IDs are GUIDs in the DB, then why not cast them as GUIDs in the entity?

Comment: Ah! I See. This treats the entity a bit like the ADO.NET dataset.

Comment: Data types on the fields here are subject to change. The project is still in the early stages.

Comment: I tried to mark both as answers but could only mark one. I marked the first one but my thanks to both of you.